# Alter WHERE clause based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause, sql-null

What I'm trying to do is based upon a parameter value, alter the WHERE clause. I've tried using a CASE expression, but realizing I'm trying to use it for a purpose it was not intended for. Here's my attempt:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN @active = 1 THEN vp.date_installed IS NOT NULL AND vp.date_removed IS NULL 
         WHEN @active = 0 THEN vp.date_removed IS NOT NULL 
         END
```

Of course the issue here is trying to use the THEN to perform beyond a simple value retrieval. So how would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend boolean logic instead:

```
WHERE 
    (@active = 1 AND vp.date_installed IS NOT NULL AND vp.date_removed IS NULL)
    OR (@active = 0 AND vp.date_removed IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Ugh. Of course. I hate it when I miss such simple things. Thank you! lol